# Installing Windows on server SSD preserving Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I have a server with a SSD and two HDDs. One of the HDD's had a Linux and a Windows partition. After Windows update we couldn't boot Linux anymore. My supervisor was able to somehow restore Linux but in the process he had to destroy the Windows Partition.

Anyway, he wants me to install Windows again over PXE but on the SSD and without overwriting the linux partition.

How can I make sure to install it on the right hard disc and not to overwrite Linux?

Comment: Installing windows on....what?  Consider correcting the question title.

Comment: Also if UEFI or BIOS, hardware, Ubuntu install and desired Windows install. Windows only installs to gpt partitioned drives with UEFI and only from MBR(msdos) drives with BIOS. If you force install in other mode than drive is partitioned it will convert drive erasing all data.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a Windows install as you normally would.  You can do it via your current computer, or put the SSD drive for Windows in a different computer and install it that way.

To install Windows you would have to boot into a Windows Install disk.  As long as you choose the SSD for your Windows install, it will only affect the install disk, not your other drives.

If you need help in installing Windows you can use a Windows support site such as http://superuser.com.

After Windows is installed on your SSD drive, boot to Ubuntu with the Windows drive attached.  Then run `sudo update-grub`.  This command will add all recognized OS installations to the grub menu, making them selectable during bootup.

**Note:**

You might also consider detaching your Ubuntu disk during the installation of Windows.  This will give you added guarantee that you will install Windows on the intended drive.  After you have the working Windows installation, reattach your Ubuntu drive.  Be sure to have your Ubuntu drive selective as your boot device in your computer's BIOS.

Comment: If I remember correctly it used to be difficult to port a drive with an installed Windows system to another computer (and make it work). Is it easier now?

Comment: I've never found it difficult to ("port") move a Windows drive to a different computer.  I did it all the time when I used to run Windows on my computers.  I always updated my computer's hardware annually and ported my Windows installation to the new system.  I don't run Windows now but I provide Windows support to clients.  I always recommend that they update their hardware, and don't have any problems with any of their computers.  Adding a windows installation to an Ubuntu computer, I find it even easier.  As in my answer, I just pop the drive in and run `sudo update-grub`.  (continued...)

Comment: @sudodus (...continued)  There used to be minor problems with drivers, which I found, updating the neccesary drivers rather seamless.  The later Windows versions have become even more seamless for driver support for the hardware change.

Comment: Good to know :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try to make a partition for linux and windows.
Then after the installation of windows, you need to reinstall grub. (Windows override the MBR Grub). 
Make sure to check if windows override other things.